# How to perform average operation in Apache Flink using Scala

Tags: apache-flink

I have a dataset like this

```
15,Rom,36,49
16,Weyoun,22,323
17,Odo,35,13
18,Jean-Luc,45,455
```

I would like to choose 3rd column and 4th column as my key and value, how can I perform average operation in Apache Flink.

I am able to achieve up to "grouping by key". But I am unable to perform average operation on the values for each key.

```scala
val lines: DataSet[String] = env.readTextFile("/home/kiran/Desktop/social_friends.csv")

val jn = lines.map(line => line.split(",")).map(word => (word(2).toString,word(3).toInt)).groupBy("0")
```

Comment: There is no average operator in Flink. You need to use "reduce" or "aggregate" and write custom UDF code.

Comment: I know it. can you please tell me how to perform it using reduce or aggregate functions.

Answer (score 4):

Pay attention, that I did change `map`, too. It emits a 3-tuple now:

```scala
val lines: DataSet[String] = env.readTextFile("/home/kiran/Desktop/social_friends.csv")

val jn = lines
  .map(line => line.split(","))
  .map(word => (word(2).toString,word(3).toInt,1))
  .groupBy("0")
  .reduce { (left, right) => (left._1, left._2 + right._2, left._3 + right._3) }
  .map(tuple => (tuple._1, tuple._2 / tuple._3))
```

Comment: There is a small correction at the last it should be tuple._2/tuple._3

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
val lines: DataSet[String] = env.readTextFile("/home/kiran/Desktop/social_friends.csv")

val jn = lines.map(line => line.split(",")).map(word => (word(2).toString, 1,word(3).toDouble)).groupBy(0).reduce { 
    (left, right) => 
      val (key, left1, left2) = left
      val (_, right1, right2) = right
      (key, left1 + left2, right1 + right2)
}.map(tuple => (tuple._1, tuple._3 / tuple._2))
```

Comment: It is throwing an error **type mismatch; found : Any required: String** near left2 and right2 . Can you please check once.in the addition operation